# Storing date with Google Apps Script, Google Cloud SQL and JDBC

Tags: sql, date, jdbc, google-apps-script

OK, this is driving me nuts. I'm working on a Google Apps Script that takes a spreadsheet as input and writes each row to a Google Cloud SQL server, but for some reason the "date" column throws the following error:

```
Invalid parameter for setObject type <?>
```

I've been trying to figure it out and I know it has something to do with the date format in JDBC / SQL, and it sounds like I need to cast the date from the spreadsheet -- which I guess is a string like '5/7/2014' (the way Google Spreadsheets formats a date by default) -- as a Date datatype, but I just can't figure out how to do it. Here's the code:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection('mydb');
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO my_table (sale_date) values (?);');
stmt.setObject(1, date_variable); //In the Spreadsheet this would look like "5/7/2014"
stmt.addBatch();
var res = stmt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

Do I need to write a function to parse the Google Spreadsheets date and turn it into a SQL DATE datatype, and if so how? It seems like running every date through a function to convert it is going to make my script a lot slower.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need a function to convert between a JavaScript date and your sql date format.
Is not correct that dates are strings in gas. They are Dates. Look at date.getTime which gives you an integer (ms since 1970) or other ways to convert to your new format. 
Wont be slow at all. Date conversion is fast. Google for how to convert itcto your format.

Comment: Thanks Zig. I tried converting it to Unix time using .getTime() and also .getTime()/1000 but I'm getting this error: Incorrect date value: '1398927600000' for column 'sale_date' at row 1

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to read about how each format works. js date.getTime() is milliseconds since 1970. each sql system can have its own format too. you cant just "cast" them, you need to  actually do the math.